# How to upload multiple files to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

Hello guys i have a form that have input file type. Currently i can only upload single file/document to the mysql **(example : localhost:3001/images/1661561304086.png)**, but i want to change it to multiple file. I already tried with my code but the link is undefined **(localhost:3001/images/undefined)** but the image is successfuly added to the folder. How do i make the link not undefined.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1013401166509527080/unknown.png

**Home.js**

```
 <div className="App">
    <Appbar />
    <div className='formInput'>
      <form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='http://localhost:3001/upload'>
     <div className='textUser'>
     </div>
          
          <input className='inputForm' value={ emailLog }  type="email" name='email' onChange={(e)=>{
            setEmailLog(e.target.value)
          }}  />
          

          <input className='inputForm'  type="text" placeholder='Invoice No' name='InvoiceNo'  />

        
          <input className='inputForm'  type="date" name='Invoice_Date'  />

          <input className='inputForm'  type="text" placeholder='Description' name='Description'  />
        
          <select className='selectBox' name='Currency' onChange={(e)=> {
            setCurrency(e.target.value);
          }}>
            <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="YEN">YEN</option>
          </select>

         
           <input className='inputForm'  type="number" placeholder='Amount' name='Amount'/>

          <input  className='custom-file-upload' multiple  type="file" name="DocumentFile" onChange={(e)=> {
            setMyFile(e.target.value);
          }} />
          
          <button className='btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**index.js**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'Images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() +  path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

app.post("/upload", upload.array('DocumentFile', 40), (req, res) => {
    const Currency = req.body.Currency
    const Title = req.body.Supplier
    const Email = req.body.email

    const InvoiceNo = req.body.InvoiceNo
    const Invoice_Date = req.body.Invoice_Date
    const Amount = req.body.Amount
    const Description = req.body.Description

    const Attachments = `localhost:3001/images/${req.files.filename}`
   

    q = "INSERT INTO payg(email, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, Title, Currency, Amount, Attachments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    db.query(q, [Email, InvoiceNo, Invoice_Date, Description, Currency, Amount, Attachments], (err, result) => {
       console.log(err)
        res.send("uploaded")
    })
})
```

const upload = multer({storage: storage});

Comment: *Currently i can only upload single file/document to the mysql* MySQL does not work with files. It seems that you upload the file to the filesystem of the host where MySQL is posessed, and then send the uploaded file name to MySQL. Is it?

Comment: yea i already give example in my question  
 https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1013401166509527080/unknown.png . if i tried to upload multiple times the file name become undefined, but the image is added to my image folder